# WordDelimiterFilterFactory and text with hyphen not giving desired results

Tags: solr

I'm currently implementing Solr as a search engine for a webshop. Most products are found, however one situating is giving me problems:

I have the following field:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
          splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
          generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
          catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"
          preserveOriginal="1"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="60"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
          splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
          generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0"
          catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"
          preserveOriginal="1"
            />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="60"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I index the following text on this field: panasonic hc-v500

I search on the following term: v500. Query type is Dismax, minimum match is set to 1.

Desired result: the document is found

Result: the document is not found

So naturally, I used the excellent 'Field analysis' tool. This gave me the following result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETLsc.png

My questions:

1. Is there a way to make Solr index the term 'v500' in this situation?
2. The field analysis result gave me the impression that the document matched (on '500'), however it was not returned. How can this be explained?

My debugQuery with explainOther returned the following result:

```
0.0 = (NON-MATCH) Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)

0.0 = no match on required clause (products_model:"v500 (500 v500)")

0.0 = (NON-MATCH) weight(products_model:"v500 (500 v500)" in 20538), product of:

  0.99999994 = queryWeight(products_model:"v500 (500 v500)"), product of:

    26.309225 = idf(products_model: v500=2 500=76 v500=2)

    0.03800948 = queryNorm

  0.0 = (NON-MATCH) fieldWeight(products_model:"v500 (500 v500)" in 20538), product of:

    0.0 = tf(phraseFreq=0.0)

    26.309225 = idf(products_model: v500=2 500=76 v500=2)

    0.5 = fieldNorm(field=products_model, doc=20538)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splitOnNumerics="0"`

[Add ability to optionally splitOnNumerics WordDelimiterFilter/Factory](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-876)